# Why is concat on array inside this.state not working?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add rendered dates inside of my array located in my component state under the key `date`, but it always returns 0.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dates: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.renderDateComp()
  }

  renderDateComp() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var dat = new Date(Date().valueOf());
      dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + i);
      this.setState({ dates: this.state.dates.concat(dat) });
      console.log(this.state.dates); //prints length of 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to do it would be to:

1. Call `setState` only once after you have the final `dates` array.
2. Log `this.state.dates` in the callback of `setState` (it will only be called after `this.state` has been properly updated by React.

The key point to note here is that `setState` is asynchronous. You probably do not need to `console.log` the array in your real code.

Read more about `setState` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    dates: []
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.renderDateComp()
}

renderDateComp() {
  var dates = this.state.dates;
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var dat = new Date(Date().valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + i);
    dates = dates.concat(dat);
  }
  this.setState({ 
    dates
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.dates); //prints length of 5
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Well firstly, state transitions aren't immediate, they are asynchronous (in most circumstances). Think of it like every time you set the state, it adds that state change to a queue of changes and React is continuously working through that queue, doing all those state changes. So if you change the state, then on the next line of code immediately print the state, the state probably won't have changed because the console.log happens IMMEDIATELY after the state change is added to the list, but BEFORE the change has actually gone through that queue.

Secondly, it's probably better to set the state AFTER the for loop, so you only have to set it once, not 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth reading the documentation of setState(). https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

It will queue the change, but there is a callback version if you want to use the new value somehow.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + props.step};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, if you do this:

```
this.setState({ dates: this.state.dates.concat(dat) }, () => console.log(this.state.dates));
```

You'll get the result you're expecting.